# Run exec() in PyCharm vs Jupyter Lab

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6, exec

I use `python3.6`, and try to use `lambda` function which I load from `.yml` file. I have the lambda in a `str` format, so I use the `exec('l = lambda x: print(x)')` function to turn it into a valid `lambda` and to assign it to a variable, but it throws the `NameError: name 'l' is not defined` exception when I try to use the lambda

The following toy example demonstrates my issue:

```
import pandas as pd

exec('l = lambda x: x+1')
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[4, 5, 6]))
df.loc[:, 'c'] = df.loc[:, 'a'].apply(l)
df
```

This code runs just fine in Jupyter Lab, but results in a `NameError: name 'l' is not defined` exception when i run it through `PyCharm`.
Also, when I use the `debug` mode in PyCharm, and try to evaluate `l` - it does show that this is a `<function <lambda> at 0x7fe604a13f28>`

What am I doing wrong? Why in JupyterLab and in PyCharm debug mode it works, but not when I run it PyCharm?

I'll highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `exec` does not automatically put things into your global scope. If you want the variables in `exec` to be added to global scope, then you need to do the following:

```
exec('l = lambda x: x + 1', globals())
```

Then, you can use `l` as a function outside of your exec scope. However, this is *not* a good way of doing things.

I believe JupyterLab automatically adds `exec` into your global scope, this is can lead to a lot of side-effects that you would rather not want. But, this is normal in a console-like environment. So if you were to run the code in your example in the PyCharm console, it would work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `eval()` instead of `exec(str, globals())`, as suggested by `@Games Brainiac`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[4, 5, 6]))
df.loc[:, 'c'] = df.loc[:, 'a'].apply(eval('lambda x: x+1'))
df
```

Cheers